# debian 'f' command?

Tags: debian, command

`top` shows:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
7476 root      20   0  1168  632  368 R  100  0.0  12:31.14 f
```

Which `f`?

```
claudiu@hussie:~$ which f
/bin/f
```

What's that?

```
claudiu@hussie:~$ man f
No manual entry for f
```

How many?

```
31755 ?        Z      0:02 [f] <defunct>
32094 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c f Opyum Team
32096 ?        S     28:02 f Opyum Team
32120 ?        Z      0:00 [f] <defunct>
32132 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c f Opyum Team
32134 ?        S     46:20 f Opyum Team
32594 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c f Opyum Team
32595 ?        S      1:46 f Opyum Team
32620 ?        Z      0:00 [f] <defunct>
32674 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c f Opyum Team
32676 ?        S      0:41 f Opyum Team
32695 ?        Z      0:00 [f] <defunct>
32710 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c f Opyum Team
32711 ?        S     91:38 f Opyum Team
32719 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh -c f Opyum Team
32720 ?        S      0:39 f Opyum Team
```

O my...

What happened?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The server has been hacked. Google "opyum team." Take server offline ASAP and restore from known-good backups.